# How to run wkhtmltopdf from php in shell

Tags: php

I'm using wkhtmltopdf for generate a invoice, everything is ok when i run it from shell

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf invoice/test.html invoice/test.pdf
```

but didn't work when i run from php

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf invoice/test.html invoice/test.pdf 2>&1');
```

I receive a information "[> ] 0% [=========>] 10%" and the file didn't create.

Any suggestion what is wrong ?

Comment: Did you try this command in console ?
I use $cmd = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf --title "'.$title.'" -T '.$topMargin.' -B '.$bottomMargin.' --dpi 75 '.$options.' '.$bodyFilePath.' '.$pdfFilePath;
 exec($cmd, $output, $return);

With $bodyFilePath the path to the html file and $pdfFilePath the path to the final PDF file. The html file is temporary and it's deleted just after this command.

Comment: yes i tried and in console is working

Comment: As apache2 user ? (commonly www-data) Did you check the access rights ?

Comment: How can i check ? Btw. exec('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf -V 2>&1'); is working

Comment: I prefer to use other people's pre-tested code, with the https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy library and (for Symfony) KnpSnappyBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree that this can be an access right issue.

Try to save to another folder/file:

Desktop/test.pdf